# Using two Simple Injector container instances with different lifestyles in c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, simple-injector, hangfire

I have a web forms application in the Global.asax of which I am buiding the Simple Injector container like below. The reason I am doing two is because I am using Hangfire to schedule recurring jobs and it does not take the Scoped lifestyle which I currently have for the application since it runs as a background worked thread. I am getting the below error when I am creating two instances of the container for my EF entities.

> The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects

Can someone please tell me how I can have two containers with different lifestyles registered in my web forms applictaion.

```
ContainerConfig.BuildContainer();
var container = ContainerConfig.BuildContainerJobs();

public static Container BuildContainer()
{
    var container = new Container();
    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new ExecutionContextScopeLifestyle();
    container.Register<TraceTimer>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
    container.Register<Entities>(() => new Entities(), Lifestyle.Scoped);
    container.Register<ReferenceDataCache>(
        () => ReferenceDataCacheFactory.Create(), Lifestyle.Scoped);

    var adapter = new SimpleInjectorAdapter(container);
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => (IServiceLocator)adapter);
    ExecutionContextScopeManager.Current = (IExecutionContextScopeManager)adapter;
    return container;
}

public static Container BuildContainerJobs()
{
    var container = new Container();
    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new ExecutionContextScopeLifestyle();

    container.Register<Entities>(() => new Entities(), Lifestyle.Transient);
    container.Register<ReferenceDataCache>(
        () => ReferenceDataCacheFactory.Create(), Lifestyle.Transient);

    var adapter = new SimpleInjectorAdapter(container);
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => (IServiceLocator)adapter);
    ExecutionContextScopeManager.Current = (IExecutionContextScopeManager)adapter;
    return container;
}
```

Global.asax code for registering

```
ContainerConfig.BuildContainer();
var container = ContainerConfig.BuildContainerJobs();
var options = new SqlServerStorageOptions
{
    QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5) // Default value
};
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
   .UseSqlServerStorage("Jobs",options);
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseDefaultActivator();

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseActivator(new SimpleInjectorJobActivator(container));
GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new SimpleInjectorAsyncScopeFilterAttribute(container));
JobsHelper.SetRecurringJob();
_backgroundJobServer = new BackgroundJobServer();
```

Comment: Please include the full stacktrace of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

This exception is not thrown by Simple Injector but by Entity Framework. This exception is typically caused by using instances of entities that are created with one `DbContext` inside *another* `DbContext`.

Unfortunately I can't be more specific and pinpoint where you are going wrong and how to fix this, because your question does not contain the appropriate details.